# HTML input validation happens after button onClick is triggered

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I have a simple form and the problem is that the validation happens after the click event is registered, thus triggering the `doSomething()` function. I would like the email validation to stop the user from submitting the form so that the function will not be triggered. How would I do that?

```
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="your email here" required/>
  <button type="submit" onClick="doSomething()">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
function doSomething(){
    // gets triggered even when the email does not pass validation
    console.log('Doing work..');
}
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qz76dyc/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the onSubmit attribute in the form, which will only call your function when all fields are validated.

```
<form onSubmit="doSomething()">
  <input type="email" placeholder="your email here" required/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
function doSomething(){
    // gets triggered even when the email does not pass validation
    console.log('Doing work..');
}
</script>
```

View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission) question to understand how to stop the form from submitting.

Thanks,